sqlplus cannot grant select v_$session right to a user
I want to grant sys.v_$session to user c##DSLI01 and so run the following command in sqlplus:
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> SELECT privilege, table_name FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS WHERE grantee = 'c##DSLI01';

no rows selected

SQL> alter session set container=XEPDB1;

Session altered.

SQL> GRANT SELECT ON V_$SESSION TO c##DSLI01;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on v_$transaction to c##DSLI01;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> SELECT privilege, table_name FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS WHERE grantee = 'c##DSLI01';

no rows selected

SQL> 

But as the result show, even after run the grant select statement, the select right still cannot granted to user c##DSLI01, why?

Change your final select statement to use uppercase "C" instead of lowercase "c". While usernames are case insensitive, they are stored in uppercase.

yes, this is the answer.
